# Problemas al intentar obtener y pasar datos de una promesa

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy realizando un trabajo con un compañero, en la cual el elige ajax para realizar peticiones a un web service, y yo utilizo fetch para realizar una peticion a una api externa, me estoy encontrando con un problema y es que al momento de obtener el dato de la api por medio de fetch me trae el dato despues de cierto tiempo, pero al momento de pasar ese dato por medio de ajax envia la variable vacia, lo cual es logico pues la respuesta de fetch tarda un tiempo en llenar mi variable, asi que lo que intente es poner un setTimeout en el ajax para esperar un tiempo y que se ejecute despues de que mi peticion fetch llene el dato, pero esto no funciona y no realiza ningun proceso:
Este es mi JavaScript:

```
$("body").on('click', '#MainContent_lnk_actualizar_foto', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let Archivo = $('#MainContent_file_foto')[0].files[0];
    let ubicacion = '';
    let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    let Id_Usuario = params.get('Id_Usuario
    const datos = new FormData
    datos.append('imagen', Archivo);
    datos.append('ubicacion', 'perfil
    fetch(`http://192.168.0.37:52456/api/Archivos/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: datos
    }).then(res => res.json())
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
        .then(response => {
            ubicacion = response.lugar
        
    setTimeout(() => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'WebService_V_Perfil.asmx/SubirArchivos',
            data: '{"Archivo": "' + ubicacion + '","Id_Usuario": "' + Id_Usuario + '"}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: result => {
                console.log(result);
                console.log(ubicacion);
            }
        })
    }, 3000
});
```

Comment: Mueve la llamada a `ajax` dentro del último `then` de tu llamada a`fetch`, con eso ya no es necesario el `setTimeout`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras si tambien lo intente pero hacer eso me genera un error 500 en el ajax

Comment: Tienes un problema de ámbito de variables. Para cuando se ejecute el código, las variables `ubicacion` e `Id_Usuario` no existirán, porque las buscará en el ámbito global y en él no existen. Además, no deberías concatenar texto para montar un JSON, puedes usar datos nativos de JavaScript. También podrías usar un IIFE para que las variables estén definidas en el temporizador. Te hago respuesta con eso último.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás usando fetch y luego jQuery para hacer llamadas, lo que no es muy elegante. Podrías hacer algo como

```javascript
$("body").on('click', '#MainContent_lnk_actualizar_foto', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let Archivo = $('#MainContent_file_foto')[0].files[0];
  let ubicacion = '';
  let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  let Id_Usuario = params.get('Id_Usuario');
  const datos = new FormData
  datos.append('imagen', Archivo);
  datos.append('ubicacion', 'perfil');
  fetch(`http://192.168.0.37:52456/api/Archivos/`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: datos
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
  .then(response => {
    ubicacion = response.lugar;
    return fetch(`'WebService_V_Perfil.asmx/SubirArchivos'`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        Archivo:  ubicacion ,
        Id_Usuario: Id_Usuario
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
  })
  .then(result => result.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(ubicacion);
  });
});
```

Comment: disculpa pero tanto el ajax como el fetch apuntan lugares diferentes

Comment: Arreglado, es lo que pasa por C&P